# rightBarButtonItem not showing on physical device

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I am building an e-commerce application that has shopping cart in rightBarButtonItem.I have implemented extension to add shopping cart barButtonItem in every UIViewControllers.My barButtonItem is showing properly in simulator devices ( including iPhone 6s,iPhone SE and iPhoneX simulators ).But it is not showing on my physical device ,iPhone 6s.Could anyone help me how to trace this issue?? Thanks for your attention 
Here is my code

```
extension UIViewController{
    func addCartBarButtonItem(){
        let cartButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        cartButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"cart"), for: .normal)
        cartButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0).isActive = true
        cartButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0).isActive = true
        cartButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.goCheckOutController), for: .touchUpInside)
        let cartBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cartButton)
        cartBarButtonItem.addBadge(number: CartDataManager.loadItems().count)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cartBarButtonItem
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Xcode's view debugging to examine the view hierarchy while running?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var rightSearchBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem?

func addCartButtonToNavigationBar(){

    self.rightSearchBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cart") , style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(goCheckOutController))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightSearchBarButtonItem;
}
```

This code is working for me